# Ubuntu 18.04 login hangs

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

Installed a new ubuntu machine 18.04. Running it vmware work station, on win10 host on Dell XPS laptop. Had used the ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64 image.
I see this peculiar behavior - login prompt comes up but immediately I get this - even before I enter my ID
[image]

Sometimes I will (re) get the login prompt after some seconds sometimes after a minute or so - keep hitting enter etc.
Never seen this behavior before - what is this?

Comment: this is not atypical, as the live installer uses cloud-init to initialize things at boot.  You can get rid of the cloud-init stuff post install by just doing `sudo apt remove cloud-init` but it's not the cause for your 'login' hanging that you're stating in your question.  Login slowness/hanging is usually a sign of something else, such as overtaxed host/VM resources, etc.

Comment: So I removed the cloud-int, so all that went away. But the behavior besides that did not change. I get the log prompt but I cant type into it for many seconds- keep trying/enter. I should not have resource issues - I have assigned 4GB to the VM, I check memory/CPU on my laptop - I have plenty to spare.

Comment: ran top command on the vm - have plenty of resources free. But saw kubernetes running - I dont think I picked an option to install it. I have to figure out how to un-install all that